# MongoDB schema optimisation for finding documents with foreign key in list

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following two MongoDB database collections.

`races`

```
{
    "_id": ..., (index)
    "track": ...,
    "distance": ...,
    "timestamp": ...,
    ...
    "runners": [
        {
            "horse_id": ...,
            "name": ...,
            "current_weight": ...,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

`horses`

```
{
    "_id": ..., (index)
    "name": ...,
    "trainer": ...,
    ...
}
```

For a given horse, I need to find all of its historical races. There are approximately 1 million races in total and each horse has on average 30 historical races. I currently use `db.races.find({"runners.horse_id": ...})` but it takes over 10 seconds each time. How can I optimise my schema? Is there some intermediate table I could use? I can hold all the data in memory, so maybe using something in Python is faster than MongoDB natively?

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on the field you are searching? Namely `{"runners.horse_id": 1 }`?

Comment: I haven’t because I’m not sure how it would help? I don’t know the race id at execution time, only the horse id for which I want to find historical races.

Comment: That's why an index on the field you _do_ have (horse id) would help. Indexes are ordered data structures that help the database quickly find data based on your search. Right now the database has no other option than to scan the full collection to find the races. Try adding the index to give it another option for searching and let us know what the results are

Comment: Down to 1ms lol. That’s nuts. I think I was conflating indexes with keys in a columnar DB. Thanks for helping my understanding